# How do I call the boolean isTested when I want to call the function

Tags: javascript

- I'm creating a js script to check a certain user account in the
  database, and if it exist it should check whether a certain given
  cellphone number is linked to that account.
- Also a boolean test has to check if the cellphone number linked to
  the account is tested and is working. If so it should pass or else it
  should conclude that the simcell is faulty, and move it from the user
  account to a collection that contains faulty simcells.

How do I go about solving this

```
function moveFaultySims(cellNo,isTested)
{ 
 {

    if(user.usercellphone=="8888888888")
    {
       if(isTested){
         //do nothing
       }
       else{
          db.faultysimcell.insert({simcell:cellNo});
       }
    }
    else{
       console.log(" device not in the default user account"+cellNo);

    }

 }
})
```

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: i'm having trouble when caling the functon , like moveFaultySims("0123855455",this where i'm having trouble specifying isTested true/false);

Comment: Please explain more, what do you mean by "trouble"? Please consider that we cannot see through your eyes and need all the relevant information in order to be able to help you. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `isTested` is the second argument, have you tried something like `moveFaultySims("0123855455, true)`?

Comment: Hi Lisa, does isTested mean "is working"? If not, you'll need another conditional inside of isTested. Also, looks like you have an extra uneeded set of curly braces for moveFaultySims.

Comment: hi Lisa what is the problem?

Comment: isTested means "is working" or not faulty which is boolean true, else is faulty which is boolean false therefor the simCell should be removed from the bunch of sms to another collection containing faulty simCells.

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveFaultySims(cellNo,isTested)
{ 
 {

    if(user.usercellphone=="8888888888")
    {
       if(1==isTested){
         //do nothing
       }
       else{
          db.faultysimcell.insert({simcell:cellNo});
       }
    }
    else{
       console.log(" device not in the default user account"+cellNo);

    }

 }
})
```

please check this code 
i changed if statement to 1==isTested

Comment: thanks it seems to work now, that 1==isTested helped .

Comment: when calling the function then what should be my second argument ? should it be true or false or "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

Are you having trouble with the evaluation of `isTested` within the if? Please elaborate the problem you are facing.

Passing anything besides empty string `''`, `null` and `false` evaluates to true, so beware if you pass strings as the second argument of the method, cause `if('false')` returns true.